# Angular Reactive form custom validators doesn't work after form reset

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have been using reactive forms since a while but, right now i am facing a issue while resetting it. My aim is inline CRUD operations to a table of records.

Create Form:

```
formGroupName.formBuilder.group({
    fieldName: '',
    fieldName1: ''
}, { validator: CustomValidator });
```

Form Reset:

```
formGroupName.reset({
    fieldName: ['', Validators.required],
    fieldName1: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

While adding a record, i display a form to the top of the table and i also perform a **this.formGroupName.reset()** function. And afterwards i reset it and i click the add button form gets reset and **CustomValidator** doesn't work at all whereas the other validators(required) do work fine. I have tried the same thing by replacing reset with patch value.

Custom validators do work when i write the code for creating the form again after the reset function which i feel is not the right solution as it makes me to write the same code again before and after calling the reset function.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on FormReset try this. worked for me

```
formGroupName.reset({
    fieldName: ('',[ Validators.required, CustomerVaidator]),
    fieldName1: ('',[ Validators.required, CustomerVaidator])
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. No doubt that i must have worked for you. To me, it didn't allow to add "(" and ")". I tried with the square brackets and both the end `formGroupName.reset({ fieldName: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidator]})` . This when i console **formGroupName.value.fieldName** it returns an array. Please advise

Comment: you can do something like this in component

`constructor(private builder:FormBuilder) {
    this.buildMyForm();
  }`

then 
`buildMyForm() {
     //build your form here
  }`
and finally on reset call reset function like this
`reset() {
    this.buildMyForm();
  }`

this is a workaround

Comment: Ur welcome. But which one worked if solution in the answer worked please upvote if possible. I ll be obliged